# Extract portion of string

Tags: c#

I have got a collection. The coll has strings:

```
Location="Theater=2, Name=regal, Area=Area1"
```

and so on. I have to extract just the Name bit from the string. For example, here I have to extract the text 'regal'

I am struggling with the query:

Collection.Location.???? (what to add here)

Which is the most short and precise way to do it?

[Edit] : What if I have to add to a GroupBy clause

Collection.GroupBy(????);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another LINQ-style answer (without the overhead of a dictionary):

```
var name = (from part in location.Split(',')
            let pair = part.Split('=')
            where pair[0].Trim() == "Name"
            select pair[1].Trim()).FirstOrDefault();
```

---

re group by (edit):

```
    var records = new[] {
        new {Foo = 123, Location="Theater=2, Name=regal, Area=Area1"},
        new {Foo = 123, Location="Name=cineplex, Area=Area1, Theater=1"},
        new {Foo = 123, Location="Theater=2, Area=Area2, Name=regal"},
    };
    var qry = from record in records
              let name = (from part in record.Location.Split(',')
                          let pair = part.Split('=')
                          where pair[0].Trim() == "Name"
                          select pair[1].Trim()).FirstOrDefault()
              group record by name;
    foreach (var grp in qry)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", grp.Key, grp.Count());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Paul's answer:

```
var location = "Theater=2, Name=regal, Area=Area1";

var foo = location
    .Split(',')
    .Select(x => x.Split('='))
    .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1]);

Console.WriteLine(foo["Name"]);
```

This populates the original string into a dictionary for easy reference. Again, no error checking or anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
Location.Split(",").Select(x => x.Split("=")[1])
```

That's the extremely lazy, completely-without-error-handling way to do it :)

Comment: That's gonna blow up if the order of the values changes.

Comment: linq is overkill and this code doesn't work for me in LinqPad (array out of bounds).    location.Split(',')[1].Split('=')[1] is correct for the 'short obfuscated fragile code' crowd

Comment: Linq is overkill? It's part of the framework! If Linq is overkill, why use strings? Why not use char arrays? Heck, why use .NET at all? Let's code it in x86 machine code!

Comment: @Matt Hamilton. Linq is overkill for this piece of code and IMO not used effectively because (despite being incorrect) it does too much. I never said Linq was overkill in general. Chill.

Answer (score 2):

The quick and dirty way is a simple IndexOf/Substring extraction:

```
string location = "Theater=2, Name=regal, Area=Area1";

int startPos = location.IndexOf("Name=") + 5;
int endPos = location.IndexOf(",", startPos);

string name = location.Substring(startPos, endPos - startPos);
```

Answer (score 2):

If Regex is an option you can use the lookaround constructs to pluck out a precise match. The sample I used below should work great in c#. The nice thing about this is that it will continue to work even if more comma delimited items are added before the name part.

```
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m =
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(
            "Theater=2, Name=regal, Area=Area", @"(?<=Name=)[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+(?=,)");
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```